# problem with maclaw CM11, constantly restarts

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, crashes, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I have a problem with a custom rom, i have a galaxy s advance, which isn't supported by cyanogen mod. Maclaw has created kitkat roms for some devices which aren't suported by cyanogen.

I now have his kitkat 4.4.4 rom running. Unfortunately maclaw hasn't got a forum.
(they are setting up one but it isn't launched yet) So i decided to ask here, since you guys have knowledge about pretty much everything, regarding this subject.
Maybe anyone else could point out what the possible cause of this problem could be.

In my case, the phone restarts after a while, but only when the device is on battery, and when the screen is locked.
Everything works perfectly when it's on charger and/or unlocked.
Is this a common problem or does it have a well known cause?
Thanks in advance for all your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with a little help i found an answer myself.this is for ppl struggling with the same problem:
To prevent those random restarts, you only have to experiment with your energy profile and your minimum clockspeed. change your CPU.(at least this worked for me) 
By default, min. clock is set at 100MHz and energyprofile is balanced. you've got to change either ONE of these. (or both if you like) I had to bump clockspeed up to 200MHz(still pretty big underclock) or change profile to powersaver. Never got the restart problem after this change, nor a problem with the dialer or the youtube app. Maybe cpu governor could be a solution too, but this did the trick for me. To unlock those options, if you can't find'em, google "cm11 developer options." then head to 'performance'.